# Upgrading CiviCRM from 5.38 to 5.44 causes DB Error: constraint violation Error

Tags: upgrade

Drupal 7
CiviCRM upgrade from 5.38.0 to 5.44.0

DB Error:

```
ALTER TABLE `civicrm_relationship_cache` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_relationship_cache_case_id` FOREIGN KEY (`case_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_case` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE; [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`drupal7_crm`.`#sql-5c_2ad8`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_relationship_cache_case_id` FOREIGN KEY (`case_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_case` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a data integrity issue. civicrm_relationship_cache table has CiviCase data which is deleted, Will need to clear those first by running below query and re-run the upgrade.

```
DELETE crc.* FROM civicrm_relationship_cache crc
LEFT JOIN civicrm_case cc
  ON crc.case_id = cc.id 
WHERE cc.id IS NULL AND crc.case_id IS NOT NULL
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Absolutely genius!!!!